# kafka consumer cannot connect

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am running a kafka and a zookeeper in docker.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                    NAMES
34a113626eb6        confluent/kafka       "/usr/local/bin/ka..."   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp                                                   kafka
552d1d787b9e        confluent/zookeeper   "/usr/local/bin/zk..."   12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2888->2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3888->3888/tcp   zookeeper
```

But when I use kafka command line to consumer message, I saw this error:

```
iMac:kafka lluo$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper `docker-machine ip bigdata`:2181 --topic bigdata
Using the ConsoleConsumer with old consumer is deprecated and will be removed in a future major release. Consider using the new consumer by passing [bootstrap-server] instead of [zookeeper].
[2018-10-09 09:09:05,504] WARN [ConsumerFetcherThread-console-consumer-62804_Russells-iMac.hsd1.ca.comcast.net-1539101285161-d8affa4e-0-0]: Error in fetch to broker 0, request Name: FetchRequest; Version: 3; CorrelationId: 0; ClientId: console-consumer-62804; ReplicaId: -1; MaxWait: 100 ms; MinBytes: 1 bytes; MaxBytes:2147483647 bytes; RequestInfo: ([bigdata,0],PartitionFetchInfo(5,1048576)) (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread)
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream.read(SocketAdaptor.java:211)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Channels.java:385)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:85)
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.readCompletely(BlockingChannel.scala:131)
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.receive(BlockingChannel.scala:122)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:102)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:86)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:135)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:135)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:135)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:31)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:134)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:134)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:134)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:31)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:133)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread.fetch(ConsumerFetcherThread.scala:114)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread.fetch(ConsumerFetcherThread.scala:35)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:151)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:112)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:64)
```

Does anyone solve this issue before?

Comment: Instead of zookeeper, try to pass bootstrap-server (9092 port by default).

Comment: You can check that ports are opened and not blocked by firewall.

Comment: Thanks Giorgos, when I use bootstrap-server, that works. Do you know the reason why the zookeeper way doesn't work?

Comment: @Russell.Luo See my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `zookeeper`, you need to use `bootstrap-server` (port 9092 is the default). 
The warning you get clearly indicates that you've been using the old consumer which is deprecated.

```
Using the ConsoleConsumer with old consumer is deprecated and will be removed in a future major release. Consider using the new consumer by passing [bootstrap-server] instead of [zookeeper].
```

Since Kafka has moved the offset storage from Zookeeper to Brokers, Kafka consumer requires `bootstrap-server` parameter as it needs to connect to the Kafka Brokers and therefore, there is no need to communicate with Zookeeper directly.

Comment: Need to set advertised listeners, though. https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: Thanks Giorgos and cricket_007.